# Reading date from webpage

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am trying to read some data from a webpage and this exception keeps getting thrown on every xpath I try.

This is what Im trying to pull from, and I just mainly want the 1

```
<tr>
    <td class="td_queue" style="border: none;">Support</td>
    <td class="td_totals" style="border: none;" id="support"><span id="changeMe0" class="new">1</span>/4/60</td>
</tr>
```

The xpath to that is `//*[@id="support"]` or `//*[@id="changeMe0"]` specifically
and the div container is `/html/body/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div`

```
            HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
            HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(Url);

            string result = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id='support']")[0].InnerHtml;
```

I also tried InnerText as well, and that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved.

For anyone wondering what I did, although completely different it worked for what I wanted to do.
I ended up just finding the JSON with the raw data in which I scraped the entire page, and split all the data into an array and used RegEx to print out the results I want.